# We have random variables $N$ and $X_i$. Find probability distribution of $X_1+...+X_N$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have two discret random variables, $N$ and $X_1,X_2,...$.

$X_i$ have the same probability distribution. Let $S_N = X_1 + ... + X_N$. The question is, how find distribution function of $S_N$?
Of course we have $F_{S_N} = \Pr(X_1 + ... + X_N \le t)$. But I don't know what can I do next.

I have the tables with values for $N$ probability distribution and $X_i$ probability distribution but if it isn't necessery I don't want prescribing it.

I will grateful for your help.

Comment: Solve the problem for each possible value of $N$. Let $p_i(s)$ be the answer for $N=n_i$. Then the answer is $\sum_i p_i(s)\Pr(N=n_i)$. There may be a simple closed form in some cases.

Comment: Are $X_1,\cdots$ assumed to be independent? If so, there is more simplification that you can do.

Comment: Of course, $X_i$ are independent.

Answer (score 2):

Sketch:

Let $S = \sum_{k=1}^N X_k$
Then the pdf of $S$ given $N$ is the $N$-th convolution of $P(X)$. To obtain the pdf of $S$ alone, marginalize over $N$: $ P(S) = \sum P(S N) = \sum P(S | N) P(N)$